# How to change my result directory in Robot framework using RIDE?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework

I am new to this framework. currently using Selenium + Python + Robot Framework + RIDE. I have 2 questions.

Kindly post the answers in the way of **RIDE implementation.**

1. By default results were storing in temp folder. How to reset to my customized location using time stamp/testcase name without deleting my past results?
2. In my application, i have to download the PDF files. How to create a customized folder and have to save inside it by using timestamp/testcase name?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It is common that every question is only a single question. This makes giving answers easier and often will require a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Arguments in RIDE **--outputdir D:\Robot\res --timestampoutputs** and set path where you want to store the result report .

[image]